# Naming selenium grid nodes. Spawning a specific node

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-server

I'm trying to implement a kind of default queues in selenium hub.
There is a possibility to specify node's name (actually its environment, smth like "firefox on ubuntu" or "chrome on windows"). Selenium grid itself has a default queue, it works according to 'First In, First Out' principle. But I want to prioritize some of my tasks given to selenium server. I have no possibility to introduce custom queue (seems like there is no API for that), that's why I decided to separate queue's logic from selenium server. I'll only call a specific node with specific name (environment) for example "firefox important node" or smth like that.

So, I want to know how to directly tell selenium which node to use for my task?
And generally, am I thinking in a right way?

Here are my configs:
hubConfig.json.erb

```
{
  "host": null,
  "port": <%= node[:selenium][:server][:port] %>,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": <%= node[:selenium][:server][:node_polling] %>,
  "cleanUpCycle": <%= node[:selenium][:server][:cleanup_cycle] %>,
  "timeout": <%= node[:selenium][:server][:timeout] %>,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "maxSession": <%= node[:selenium][:server][:max_session] %>
}
```

nodeConfig.json.erb

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }, {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }, {
      "browserName": "phantomjs",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": <%= node[:selenium][:node][:max_session] %>,
    "port": <%= node[:selenium][:node][:port] %>,
    "host": "<%= node[:fqdn] %>",
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": <%= node[:selenium][:node][:register_cycle] %>,
    "hubPort": <%= node[:selenium][:server][:port] %>
  }
}
```

And my Driver class:

```
  ...
  def remote_driver
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote,
      :url                  => "http://myhub.com:4444/wd/hub",
      :http_client          => client,
      :desired_capabilities => capabilities
    )
  end

  def capabilities
    Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.send(
      "firefox",
      :javascript_enabled    => true,
      :css_selectors_enabled => true,
      :takes_screenshot      => true
    )
  end

  def client
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.timeout = 360
    client
  end
  ...
```

I still don't know how to use specified node for my task.
If I try to start a driver adding `:name => "firefox important node"` and extend nodeConfig.json.erb's configuration with

```
environments:
   - name:    "firefox important node"
     browser: "*firefox"
   - name:    "Firefox36 on Linux"
     browser: "*firefox"
```

selenium just starts random firefox browser on a random node. How can I control it?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows how you could implement a custom Prioritizer for Selenium Grid. This allows you to define any complex queuing logic you like.

http://selenium.polteq.com/en/use-custom-prioritizer-for-selenium-grid-hub/

Comment: Java code is quite messy, I tried to write similar code in Ruby, but I didn't achieve expected result. We decided to use two separate selenium hubs, one for priority queue, another for regular.

Comment: it's more a question of architecture - extension vs external code. by writing an extension you can re-use the same nodes to achieve your goal - it seems significantly better (though yes - you'll have to get messy in java)

Comment: Your link is broken @Kenn

Comment: Here is a snapshot from 2014 https://web.archive.org/web/20140528054638/http://selenium.polteq.com/en/use-custom-prioritizer-for-selenium-grid-hub/